# Disabling/hiding rather than deleting

Tags: best-practices, deleting

From what I understand, it's generally best practice to design a system with user access to delete "records" to only hide/disable that record and not actually delete it. This typically ends up being (example) a flag in a database like "enabled" which gets changed to 0 when a user "deletes" a record. This doesn't just pertain to databases but things such as web systems, files and so on.

Is this generally true, and are there any good write-ups/papers on this matter?

Comment: This question is going to get closed for multiple reasons, check out the FAQ next time before posting.  Regardless, I'll give my $0.02 below.

Comment: Software design and development questions are ***WILDLY OFF TOPIC*** for Server Fault. We have both [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [programmers.SE] for this sort of discussion.  That said, the answer to your question is this is generally a good way to design systems (it makes undeleting easier, and in the event a malicious user starts "deleting everything" recovery is as simple as flipping the bit back). Stack Exchange uses this principle for deleting things - A flag is set which makes them "invisible" to most users. If you have enough rep search for `deleted:1` to see them.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to disable records for the most part except for when the data is not important to the user.  For instance, if I'm dealing in user accounts I would want to disable and only delete after a long period of time.  However, if I'm dealing with something simple such as a list of codes or values I would probably delete them entirely.

The real answer: it depends with each system and the requirements behind the system.